# Creating a database of foods in Java

Tags: java, database

Ive just started learning Java and I spent most of the day watching video tutorials, however now I've decided to do something practical, as I dont think I can absorb anymore information today.

I had an idea to develop a fitness app a while ago, but was hit by how difficult that actually is without any knowledge, so I thought I will start by just creating a macro counter. I created a class:

```
public class Food {

    private String name;
    public int weight;
    private int calories;
    private int protein;
    private int fat;
    private int carbs;

    public int tCals = weight * calories;
    public int tProtein = weight * protein;
    public int tFat = weight * fat;
    public int tCarbs = weight * carbs;

    public void macrocounter(){
        System.out.println("Total calories: " + tCals);
        System.out.println("\nProtein: " + tProtein);
        System.out.println("\nCarbs: " + tCarbs);
        System.out.println("\nFat: " + tFat);
        System.out.println("-------------");

    }


}
```

Now what I am having problems with is creating a database. I want to add at least 10 simple meals to begin with, they would all have the macros set in stone, the user would just type in the name of the meal and how many grams he ate, then the app would recognize the food from the database, fill in weight, and print out the total macros.

I am not asking here how to write the specific code, just can you point me to what I should read up on more to be able to do this? Java is an insanely vast language, and I am having trouble to find the actual information I need on creating a database.

Thank you.

Comment: I really think you need to broaden your understanding of what a database is, and also think through how far you want to carry this project.  That being said, look up creating enums in java.  Creating enums to hold static data can get out of hand fast though, so if you're looking to get complex with this project, you are really going to need more experience.  You can also use simple flat files that contain data (.txt, .xml, etc.) to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I do need to learn a lot more if I want this project to take off, that is why I start with very basic things just to do a little bit of practice. I will make sure to read about enums!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want just to store the data in main memory? or in a real database to disk?

If it is the first option, you can do this:

```
ArrayList<Food> foods =  new ArrayList<Food>();
```

Once you have your list, you can add things like this:

```
Food f = new Food(...data...); //You need a constructor
                               //to pass the data.

foods.add(f);
```

To consult it you can do a number of things:

```
Food f0 = foods.get(0);
Food f1 = foods.get(1);
```

You can also query for a particular object:

```
if (foods.contains(f0) {
    // ...
}
```

Google for "java class ArrayList" and you'll see what you can do.

If, on the contrary, you want to create a real database, you need to read about JDBC drivers. To begin, I recommend you sqlite.

```
package consultarcalibredb;

import java.sql.*;


public class ConsultarCalibreDB {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;

        int id;
        String title, author, path;
        try  {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/user/folder/file.db");
            String sql = "select id, title, author_sort, path from books where author_sort like '%orwell%'";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            System.out.println("id\ttitulo\tautor\tpath");
            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt("id");
                title = rs.getString("title");
                author = rs.getString("author_sort");
                path = rs.getString("path");

                System.out.println(id+"\n"+title+
                "\n"+author+"\n"+path);

                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very good response, exactly what I was looking for. I will try out the first method right now, and work on the second one tomorrow, as long term my goal is to have a database in a disk (online if I ever manage to create an interface and release the app).

Answer (score 1):

Some oneline tutorials are good.  But I would consider investing in a good Java book.  I found BigJava Cay S. Horstmann a really helpful source of information. It gives you plenty of exercises and opportunity to practice code, and explains things in a very clear way.  I would only go to online tutorials if I had trouble following a certain methodology in a book.  But I wouldnt use them as a learning resource, as they may not be correct.

It is an expensive book though but you might be able to get an older edition for cheeap or a second hand copy.  Oracle's website also has useful written tutorials for you to follow https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/  But I found the book easier to follow.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java  This is also a good website, it gives you projects that matches your skill set, and keeps a record on how you do.  I not tried it myself yet, but i heard great things - good luck

Comment: This is not an answer.....

Comment: I can't comment I havn't reached 50 rep - only on my own answers

Comment: That does not mean that you write comments as answers!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will look up the book you mentioned, though I dont think I can buy it in my country, maybe eBay..

Comment: Debosmit seriously!? its pointing him in the right direction, and giving them good advice about learning coding.  Am I not supposed to say anything even though I know it would help someone..SO really needs to chill out sometimes.  Plus it is an answer! and its giving them links to practice the code and learn about database structures in Java!!!

Comment: This answer is also good. Actually I started learning Java with a book. It was 1999. Reading a book gives you perspective and completness. Also, having paid for it, you won't give up reading so quickly than with an online tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I got a lot of suggestions on what I should learn and from where. I dont know how to close the question, but if you do, please do so.